# C++ , reading file lines by numbers

Tags: c++, ifstream

I want to make console project that reads file by numbers. Example: finding by numbers **1 2** and it only prints in console lines of text from folder that contains those numbers

```
   bibi                ceki     1     2
 hasesh              cekiii     1     3
   krki                 cko     1     2
```

In this case it would just print out "bibi ceki" and "krki cko". 
In my code there are many missing things. I don't have a loop that checks if there are right numbers, but here is best I could do and what I tried :

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char str1[10], str2[10];
    int raz, ode;
    ifstream infile("file.txt");
    while (infile.good()) {
        fscanf(infile, "%s %s %d %d", str1, str2, &raz, &ode); //this thing cant be used lik this 
        while(raz==1 && ode==2) {
            string sLine;
            getline(infile, sLine);
            cout << sLine << endl;
        }
    }
    infile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see the line with fscanf is not working and I don't know what to do there .

I need some help and suggestion if there is a better way to do this , and please be specific as much as possible , I'm new in c++/c .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mixing C fscanf function and C++ ifstream.

I would suggets using C++ and in this case you can use operator>> like this:

```
std::string str1, str2 ;
...
//substitute the following line with the one below
//fscanf(infile, "%s %s %d %d", str1, str2,&raz,&ode);
infile >> str1 >> str2 >> raz >> ode ;
```

Comment: When talking about C++ it's nice to see actual C++ being used. Nice!

Comment: yeah , you are right , I was using C before starting with c++ . It's not calling error anymore , but still not printing lines. Thank you

Comment: Does it print anything at all? Can you see what you get with a debugger? Or just add a std::cout << str1 << " " << str2 << " " << raz << " " << ode << std::endl ; to see what you get...

Comment: @kuki `while(raz==1 && ode==2)` reaches an inifnite loop once `raz == 1` and `ode == 2`. Change it to `if(raz==1 && ode==2)`.  Also, no need for `getline()` since you already parsed `str1` and `str2`. `if(raz==1 && ode==2) { cout << str1 << " " << str2 << endl; } ` will do.

Comment: @marom , loop **while(raz==1 &&  ode==2)** keeps printing first line infinitly

Comment: @raymelfrancisco , It prints now , but it prints all lines

Comment: Here is what I found out . If raz==1 and ode==3 it will print only line with those numbers, but if I use raz==1 and ode ==2 it will print all lines , even the line with number 3.

Comment: @kuki Tried it and it works fine. `raz==1 && ode==2` prints `bibi ceki`, `krki cko`. While `raz == 1 && ode == 3` prints `hasesh cekiii`. I changed `while(raz==1 && ode==2)` to `if(raz==1 && ode==2) { cout << str1 << " " << str2 << endl; }`

Comment: IT WORKED !! :D @raymelfrancisco , how I can mark your comment as answer ?

Comment: @kuki You can suggest it as an edit to the given answer above, then accept his answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82847/discussion-between-kuki-and-raymelfrancisco).

Answer (score 4):

You can read line by line using `std::getline` until code matches and when it does, you can `push_back` the names into a `std::vector`. You can also structure your file with a delimiter, for example `'|'` so that you read up until that character for names and the rest for codes. Example file would be:

```
bibi ceki|1 2
hasesh cekiii|1 3
krki cko|1 2
```

Here is an example of how you could achieve that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream in_file("file.txt", ios::in);
    vector<string> vec;
    string names; // store names like: "bibi ceki"
    string codes; // store codes like: "1 2"

    while (getline(in_file, names, '|')) {
        getline(in_file, codes, '\n');
        if (codes == "1 2")
            vec.push_back(names);
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i != vec.size(); ++i)
        cout << vec[i] << endl;

    in_file.close();
}
```

Output:

```
bibi ceki
krki cko
```

Comment: I got some weird error . **error: range-based 'for' loops are not allowed in C++98 mode|** . I think this will work , I just need to fix this error .

Comment: @kuki, you can use a normal for loop, I edited the answer to use that instead. The range based for loop works when compiled with `-std=c++11`

Comment: Thank you for your effort , looks like I found out another solution that work fine with my type of txt file.